# Choosing "Approved Content" on YouTube Kids

Tags: youtube

I set up YouTube Kids for my child with the "Approved content only" setting.

During initial setup, it asked me which videos I want to approve. I only approved one video, figuring I could approve more later. This resulted in her seeing "Approved for you" with that one video, which she could loop as much as she wanted ad-free. That was awesome, but I'm getting a bit tired of that one approved video.

Now I can't find any way through the web UI (or even the Android mobile UI) to approve more videos. The YouTube Kids Parental Guide also shows nothing about approving or whitelisting content.

How do you approve new videos in YouTube Kids?